# Maven dependencies cant be accessed in Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to run a java applcication from a docker file. The application is run via maven.

When I try to spin up a container from the following image, I get the following errors.

```
    [ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.5/cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5/cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20180813/json-20180813.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] /temproj/src/test/java/pages/terms/Terms_Chrome.java:[1,1] cannot access pages.terms
[ERROR]   zip END header not found
[ERROR] /temproj/src/test/java/config/RunCukesTest.java:[1,1] cannot access config
[ERROR]   zip END header not found
[ERROR] /temproj/src/test/java/utils/SetProperty.java:[1,1] cannot access utils
[ERROR]   zip END header not found
[ERROR] /temproj/src/test/java/pages/sign_in/SignIn.java:[1,1] cannot access pages.sign_in
[ERROR]   zip END header not found
```

My Docker file

```
FROM maven

COPY . /temproj


RUN mkdir -p /root/.m2/repository/ \
    mvn install

WORKDIR /temproj


ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "verify"]
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ecs.googleuat</groupId>
    <artifactId>googleuat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <properties>
        <sele.lib.version>3.141.59</sele.lib.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
       <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <glue>
                                <package>
                                    steps
                                </package>
                            </glue>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                            <format>json,html</format>
                            <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>acceptance-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- vinsdocker is org name. -->
                    <!-- containertest is the name of the image /  application  -->
                    <repository>chrisdocker/selcontainertest</repository>
                    <!-- version of your image: could be sprint11 or release5 etc -->
                    <tag>googletest</tag>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${sele.lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${sele.lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>${sele.lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Appreciate some help on resolving this, I think it might have something to do with user permissions inside the container perhaps.

Comment: You're not trying to run a Java application in docker - you're trying to run a Java _build_ in docker. Why? This smells of an XY problem to me.

Comment: If you really like to build inside the Docker container you should use a mounted volume to insert the repository cache (.m2/repository) into the container...which means also you need to allow to have network access from inside the container to  the outside to a repository manager...

Answer (score 1):

The base maven image already has an entrypoint script ([see source](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/05f4802aa5c253dcf75fe967c6f45b3fb1e2f26e/jdk-11-slim/mvn-entrypoint.sh)). Why are you overriding it ? Use `CMD ["mvn", "verify"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM maven
COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN mvn install

ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "verify"]
```